# Ghost text frame

Tags: adobe-indesign

When I turn on hidden characters, I have an end-of-story symbol (#) and I can't select it for deletion. Apparently it is locked. It is preventing text flow. The text ends on the previous page in the middle of the page and flows directly to the top of the next page. (CS[image]6)

Comment: Found the problem. It was a style conflict with different keep settings. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Its not a ghost, its an actual object that exists and where you're not looking.. :)

That could be some left over text box on the master page, on a locked layer or locked object on your actual page. Check all of these.

CTRL+ALT+L to force unlock everything on a page, including master pages.

Comment: Everything is unlocked. In two locations in this document, text in the middle of a recto page is jumping to the top of verso.